How to write configuration file for X11 - Layout section for selecting a screen
According to this output from /var/log/Xorg.0.log when I want to start X by writing

startx

Then the output shows.
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1198.198] Current Operating System: Linux stm32-os 6.1.82 #1 PREEMPT Tue Sep 10 21:04:28 CEST 2024 armv7l
[  1198.199] Kernel command line: root=PARTUUID=e91c4e10-16e6-4c0e-bd0e-77becf4a3582 rootwait rw   console=ttySTM0,115200
[  1198.199] xorg-server 2:21.1.12-1ubuntu1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  1198.199] Current version of pixman: 0.42.2
[  1198.199]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1198.199] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1198.200] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Apr 19 14:44:17 2024
[  1198.202] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1198.202] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1198.204] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1198.205] (**) |-->Screen "DefaultScreen" (0)
[  1198.205] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1198.206] (**) |   |-->Device "Mali FBDEV"
[  1198.206] (==) No monitor specified for screen "DefaultScreen".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1198.206] (**) Allowing byte-swapped clients
[  1198.206] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1198.206] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1198.207] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  1198.207] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[  1198.207] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  1198.207] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  1198.207]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1198.207] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  1198.207]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1198.207] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  1198.207]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1198.207] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  1198.207]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1198.207] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  1198.207]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1198.208] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[  1198.208] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1198.208] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  1198.208] (II) Loader magic: 0x5a9008
[  1198.208] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1198.208]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1198.208]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[  1198.208]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[  1198.208]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  1198.213] (--) using VT number 2

[  1198.213] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[  1198.219] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  1198.220] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/platform/soc/5a001000.display-controller/drm/card0
[  1198.221] (II) no primary bus or device found
[  1198.221]    falling back to /sys/devices/platform/soc/5a001000.display-controller/drm/card0
[  1198.221] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1198.223] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1198.232] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1198.232]    compiled for 1.21.1.11, module version = 1.0.0
[  1198.232]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  1198.232] (II) LoadModule: "armsoc"
[  1198.233] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/armsoc_drv.so
[  1198.234] (II) Module armsoc: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1198.234]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.4.1
[  1198.235]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1198.235]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[  1198.235] (II) ARMSOC: Driver for ARM Mali compatible chipsets
[  1198.237] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for armsoc
[  1198.237] (II) No BusID or DriverName specified - opening /dev/dri/card0
[  1198.237] (II) Got BusID 5a001000.display-controller
[  1198.238] (II) Opened DRM
[  1198.238] (II)    DeviceName is [/dev/dri/card0]
[  1198.238] (II)    bus_id is [5a001000.display-controller]
[  1198.238] (II)    DriverName is [stm]
[  1198.238] (II)    version is [1.0.0]
[  1198.238] (II) Screen:0,  CRTC:-1
[  1198.238] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[  1198.239] (II) ARMSOC(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "DefaultScreen" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[  1198.239] (**) ARMSOC(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[  1198.239] (==) ARMSOC(0): RGB weight 888
[  1198.239] (==) ARMSOC(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  1198.239] (==) ARMSOC(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  1198.239] (II) No BusID or DriverName specified - opening /dev/dri/card0
[  1198.239] (II) Got BusID 5a001000.display-controller
[  1198.239] (II) Opened DRM
[  1198.239] (II)    DeviceName is [/dev/dri/card0]
[  1198.240] (II)    bus_id is [5a001000.display-controller]
[  1198.240] (II)    DriverName is [stm]
[  1198.240] (II)    version is [1.0.0]
[  1198.240] (II) UnloadModule: "armsoc"
[  1198.240] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[  1198.241] (EE) Fatal server error:
[  1198.241] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[  1198.241] (EE) Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help. 
[  1198.241] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  1198.241] (EE) 
[  1198.243] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

The problem here is that it cannot find the layout section. So, instead, it using a default screen, which seems not to work because it has a usable configuration.
[  1198.202] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1198.202] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1198.204] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1198.205] (**) |-->Screen "DefaultScreen" (0)
[  1198.205] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1198.206] (**) |   |-->Device "Mali FBDEV"
[  1198.206] (==) No monitor specified for screen "DefaultScreen". Using a default monitor configuration.

My device have this configuration
[?2004hroot@stm32-os:~# modetest -M stm
[?2004l
Encoders:
id  crtc    type    possible crtcs  possible clones 
31  38  DPI 0x00000001  0x00000001

Connectors:
id  encoder status      name        size (mm)   modes   encoders
32  31  connected   HDMI-A-1        1210x680        7   31
  modes:
    index name refresh (Hz) hdisp hss hse htot vdisp vss vse vtot
  #0 1920x1080 30.00 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 74250 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver
  #1 1920x1080 25.00 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 74250 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver
  #2 1920x1080 24.00 1920 2558 2602 2750 1080 1084 1089 1125 74250 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver
  #3 1280x720 60.00 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 74250 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver
  #4 1280x720 50.00 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 74250 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver
  #5 720x576 50.00 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 27000 flags: nhsync, nvsync; type: driver
  #6 720x480 59.94 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 27000 flags: nhsync, nvsync; type: driver
  props:
    1 EDID:
        flags: immutable blob
        blobs:

        value:
            00ffffffffffff00506c866511100100
            271b0103807944780a0dc9a057479827
            12484c2108008140a940818081c0a9c0
            01010101010104740030f2705a80b058
            8a0020c23100001e023a801871382d40
            582c4500b9a84200001e000000fc0054
            434c20534d4152542054560a000000fd
            00324b1e5023000a20202020202001f0
            020340f257909f051420041312110302
            161507060121225d625e5f6429090707
            15175055170083010000e200ff6e030c
            002000b84421008001020304e3050301
            023a801871382d40582c4500b9a84200
            001e011d007251d01e206e285500b9a8
            4200001e000000000000000000000000
            000000000000000000000000000000a3
    2 DPMS:
        flags: enum
        enums: On=0 Standby=1 Suspend=2 Off=3
        value: 0
    5 link-status:
        flags: enum
        enums: Good=0 Bad=1
        value: 0
    6 non-desktop:
        flags: immutable range
        values: 0 1
        value: 0
    4 TILE:
        flags: immutable blob
        blobs:

        value:
    33 dithering:
        flags: enum
        enums: Off=0 On=1
        value: 0

CRTCs:
id  fb  pos size
38  0   (0,0)   (1280x720)
  #0 1280x720 60.00 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 74250 flags: phsync, pvsync; type: driver
  props:
    24 VRR_ENABLED:
        flags: range
        values: 0 1
        value: 0
    28 GAMMA_LUT:
        flags: blob
        blobs:

        value:
    29 GAMMA_LUT_SIZE:
        flags: immutable range
        values: 0 4294967295
        value: 256

Planes:
id  crtc    fb  CRTC x,y    x,y gamma size  possible crtcs
34  0   0   0,0     0,0 0           0x00000001
  formats: AR24 XR24 RG24 RG16 AR15 XR15 AR12 XR12 C8
  props:
    8 type:
        flags: immutable enum
        enums: Overlay=0 Primary=1 Cursor=2
        value: 1
    30 IN_FORMATS:
        flags: immutable blob
        blobs:

        value:
            01000000000000000900000018000000
            01000000400000004152323458523234
            52473234524731364152313558523135
            41523132585231324338202000000000
            ff010000000000000000000000000000
            0000000000000000
        in_formats blob decoded:
             AR24:  LINEAR(0x0)
             XR24:  LINEAR(0x0)
             RG24:  LINEAR(0x0)
             RG16:  LINEAR(0x0)
             AR15:  LINEAR(0x0)
             XR15:  LINEAR(0x0)
             AR12:  LINEAR(0x0)
             XR12:  LINEAR(0x0)
             C8:  LINEAR(0x0)
    36 alpha:
        flags: range
        values: 0 65535
        value: 65535
    37 zpos:
        flags: immutable range
        values: 0 0
        value: 0
39  0   0   0,0     0,0 0           0x00000001
  formats: AR24 RG24 RG16 AR15 AR12 C8
  props:
    8 type:
        flags: immutable enum
        enums: Overlay=0 Primary=1 Cursor=2
        value: 0
    30 IN_FORMATS:
        flags: immutable blob
        blobs:

        value:
            01000000000000000600000018000000
            01000000300000004152323452473234
            52473136415231354152313243382020
            3f000000000000000000000000000000
            0000000000000000
        in_formats blob decoded:
             AR24:  LINEAR(0x0)
             RG24:  LINEAR(0x0)
             RG16:  LINEAR(0x0)
             AR15:  LINEAR(0x0)
             AR12:  LINEAR(0x0)
             C8:  LINEAR(0x0)
    41 alpha:
        flags: range
        values: 0 65535
        value: 65535
    42 zpos:
        flags: immutable range
        values: 1 1
        value: 1

Frame buffers:
id  size    pitch

[?2004hroot@stm32-os:~# 

Question:
How can I create a configuration file, that my linux kernel or what ever going to read that file, when I'm writing startx to get the graphical screen loaded up?

How should the file look like?
Where should it be placed?
What should the file contain?

Edit:
This occurs on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS armhf
Edit 2:
I tried X -configure.
[?2004hroot@stm32-os:~# X -configure
[?2004l

X.Org X Server 1.21.1.11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux stm32-os 6.1.82 #1 PREEMPT Tue Sep 10 21:04:28 CEST 2024 armv7l
Kernel command line: root=PARTUUID=e91c4e10-16e6-4c0e-bd0e-77becf4a3582 rootwait rw   console=ttySTM0,115200
xorg-server 2:21.1.12-1ubuntu1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.42.2
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Apr 21 12:47:20 2024
List of video drivers:
    amdgpu
    armsoc
    ati
    nouveau
    radeon
    modesetting
    fbdev
    vesa
(++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
[?2004hroot@stm32-os:~# 

And the /root/xorg.config.new
less /root/xorg.conf.new
[?2004l

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "X.org Configured"
        Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
        InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
        InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
        ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
        FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load  "glx"
EndSection

[7m/root/xorg.conf.new[27m[K
[KSection "InputDevice"
:[K
[K        Identifier  "Keyboard0"
:[K
[K        Driver      "kbd"
:[K
[KEndSection
:[K
[K
:[K
[KSection "InputDevice"
:[K
[K        Identifier  "Mouse0"
:[K
[K        Driver      "mouse"
:[K
[K        Option      "Protocol" "auto"
:[K
[K        Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
:[K
[K        Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
:[K
[KEndSection
:[K
[K
:[K
[KSection "Monitor"
:[K
[K        Identifier   "Monitor0"
:[K
[K        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
:[K
[K        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
:[K
[KEndSection
:[K
[K
:[K
[KSection "Device"
:[K
[K        ### Available Driver options are:-
:[K
[K        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
:[K
[K        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
:[K
[K        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
:[K
[K        ### [arg]: arg optional
:[K
[K        #Option     "Debug"                     # [<bool>]
:[K
[K        #Option     "NoFlip"                    # [<bool>]
:[K
[K        #Option     "DRICard"                   # <i>
:[K
[K        #Option     "BusID"                     # <str>
:[K
[K        #Option     "DriverName"                # <str>
:[K
[K        #Option     "DRI2MaxBuffers"            # <i>
:[K
[K        #Option     "InitFromFBDev"             # <str>
:[K
[K        #Option     "UMP_LOCK"                  # [<bool>]
:[K
[K        Identifier  "Card0"
:[K
[K        Driver      "armsoc"
:[K
[KEndSection
:[K
[K
:[K
[KSection "Screen"
:[K
[K        Identifier "Screen0"
:[K
[K        Device     "Card0"
:[K
[K        Monitor    "Monitor0"
:[K
[K        SubSection "Display"
:[K
[K                Viewport   0 0
:[K
[K                Depth     1
:[K
[K        EndSubSection
:[K
[K        SubSection "Display"
:[K
[K                Viewport   0 0
:[K
[K                Depth     4
:[K
[K        EndSubSection
:[K
[K        SubSection "Display"
:[K
[K                Viewport   0 0
:[K
[K                Depth     8
:[K
[K        EndSubSection
:[K
[K        SubSection "Display"
:[K
[K                Viewport   0 0
:[K
[K                Depth     15
:[K
[K        EndSubSection
:[K
[K        SubSection "Display"
:[K
[K                Viewport   0 0
:[K
[K                Depth     16
:[K
[K        EndSubSection
:[K
[K        SubSection "Display"
:[K
[K                Viewport   0 0
:[K
[K                Depth     24
:[K
[K        EndSubSection
:[K
[KEndSection
[K[?2004hroot@stm32-os:~# 


The display driver is not detecting any monitor properties. Do you have an actual display screen connected to the system, or are you running these commands via a SSH or serial port connection? If there is a connected display, does it use a standard autoprobeable external display interface like HDMI or DisplayPort, or does it use something like LTDC or DSI interface instead? Is the DRM KMS overview in STM32 MPU ecosystem documentation applicable to your case?

@telcoM Hi! Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question. Yes, my HDMI can communicate with the screen. No problem there. I can for example connect my screen using modetest -M stm -s 32:1280x720-60 and see some colors at the screen. Hence, the startx won't display my desktop.

Disclaimer: I have plenty of experience on the X.org X11 server on Linux, but no personal experience whatsoever on setting it up on ARM hardware.
I noticed that the release notes of the STM32 indicate that Wayland and its Weston display composer have been updated specifically for STM32 - but there is no mention of the corresponding X.org display drivers. I'm afraid that might mean anything in between these cases:

Best case: the ARMSOC X.org driver already supports your hardware well enough that no changes were needed - it's just that autoprobing the displays doesn't quite work, and you might need to configure the display resolutions and pixel clock limits in an old-school way. From your question, I guess this is what you're hoping for.
Worst case: the STM32 developers may have put all their GUI driver efforts into Wayland instead of X.org, and only Wayland is currently documented and working. Perhaps the kernel stm DRM driver has just enough features implemented for Wayland, but something the X11 server needs is still unimplemented. Or perhaps the ARMSOC X11 driver needs a STM32-specific patch.

The stm kernel DRM driver seems to be specific to the STM32 platform, as I could not find any documentation about it elsewhere.
So, if you just want a GUI session and don't particularly care whether it's X11 or Wayland - then try this command instead of startx:
systemctl restart weston-graphical-session

like it says in the STM32 documentation. In that case, the configuration file for the Wayland-based GUI display would be /etc/xdg/weston/weston.ini.

But if you specifically want X11, you can ask the X11 display server to produce a configuration file template for you, by running this command as root:
Xorg -configure

This should produce a /root/xorg.conf.new file, which should be a more or less complete template xorg.conf file. Note that you probably won't need the complete configuration file, as the modern X server is generally pretty good at autoprobing the hardware.
So you might pick from the configuration template just the one or two sections the driver seems to be having trouble autoprobing: perhaps just the Monitor and maybe Screen sections. Fill them out with valid data (see man xorg.conf for details) and place just those sections into a /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/stm32.conf file, for example.

The really old-school way to configure the X11 server would be to take the whole template, copy it to /etc/X11/xorg.conf and fill out any missing data (e.g. the monitor pixel clock limits and maximum resolutions, as the driver doesn't appear to be able to autoprobe them currently).
This might be more trouble than it's worth, as you might have to fill out any input device configuration (i.e. configuration information for keyboard and mouse) too.

Great answer! But before I can accept the answer, I want to tell you that I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on my ARM device. Yes, built my own Linux distro. Also I have updated my question. It's about the new log from X -configure. Thank you.

I'm uninstalling x-server and installing wayland.

YES! weston is the right solution. Now I can see my desktop with clock, X-term etc. I'm using ratpoison as window manager. Never used it before. Let's see if it's good.

See the log here when I starting weston https://pastebin.com/0xB6afLc

wrote a new question about that! Thank you by the way. Your answer is the solution.
